# Calculates and outputs the factorial of variable n (n already initialized).

Tags: javascript

Here inbelow is the code. Could anybody tell that what's wrong with the code? The purpose is to the factorial result of var n. (suppose it's already declared)

```
   for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    var n1 = Math.floor(rc4Rand.getRandomNumber() * 7) + 3;
    document.write("The factorial of " + n1 + " is ");
    outputFactorial(n1);
    }

   function outputFactorial(n)
   { 
    //I have to add some context here to post this question.
   if (n1 == 0) {
                  return 1;
                }

    else {
            return (n1 * factorial(n1 - 1));
          }
    }
     document.write(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake: the name of the argument in your `outputFactorial()` function is `n`, but you're using `n1` throughout the function, and thus entering an infinite recursion loop (if `n1 != 0`).

Comment: Is that all ? Sorry 15 characters have to put to post comment

Comment: @Longway_togo Try it and see!

Comment: `document.write(n)` is outside of the function.

Comment: @andars As it should be, as the function is recursive and only its outermost result should be printed. However, the print should probably come before the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

1. The **factorial** function must be change to **outputFactorial**
2. The **n1**  variables needs to be changed to **n** in the **outputFactorial** function
3. You have to do is **Document.write(outputFactorial(n1));**
4. Remove the outside of function **Document.write**